# The effect of all zero value as the input of SVM

Tags: svm

I am running a set of input parameters in SVM. One if the input contains all zero values. I know that this kind input should be omitted, but I don't know the reason why. Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but I'm assuming you're trying to say one of the features you used for SVM has values containing zeros, and how does this affect SVM in terms of making a decision.

Think about it in a Euclidean hyperplane(three dimensions for better visualization), if the input contains all zeros where will you plot a point related to that feature on the hyperplane. The value of that point will be zero, so effectively you're not using that feature at all.